# I want to get the Full Path of a Tree Structure for any child selected down the tree. Is there any direct API that can be used?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to get the Full Path of a Tree Structure for any child selected down the tree. Is there any direct API that can be used ?
I am using CTreeCtrl class of MFC to implement

Comment: I am able to achieve it using teh following code HTREEITEM hCurrentItem = pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem;
 while (hCurrentItem != NULL)
 {
  CString sCurrentItemText = m_cTreeCtrl.GetItemText(hCurrentItem);
  sFullTreepath = sCurrentItemText + _T("\\") + sFullTreepath;
  hCurrentItem = m_cTreeCtrl.GetParentItem(hCurrentItem);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your required info using CTreeCtrl::SetItemData and Collect back using CTreeCtrl::GetItemData and the parent can be obtained using CTreeCtrl::GetParentItem. Write a simple function to recursively go back using GetParentItem and create a path of your wish.

Comment: I am able to achieve it using teh following code HTREEITEM hCurrentItem = pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem;
 while (hCurrentItem != NULL)
 {
  CString sCurrentItemText = m_cTreeCtrl.GetItemText(hCurrentItem);
  sFullTreepath = sCurrentItemText + _T("\\") + sFullTreepath;
  hCurrentItem = m_cTreeCtrl.GetParentItem(hCurrentItem);
 }